# Jquery - Why is the JS dead on this after i add these lines?

Tags: jquery, function, callback, jcarousel

Im trying to do a callback in jcarousel where after an image becomes visible it fires this function.

alas soon as i try it it stops the js working and nothing occurs.

can anyone point out what could be wrong?

cheers,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    easing: 'backout',
        animation: 1000,
    vertical: true,
        scroll: 1,
    itemVisibleInCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: itemVisibleIn}, 
       });
});

function itemVisibleIn(){
    $("#gallerydescription").html( $(this).attr("alt"));  }, 
  function () {
    $("#gallerydescription").html("");
  }
);
 });
}

 </script>
```

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ <--  documentation

Comment: Have you checked in Firebug/Chrome Inspector/Opera Dragonfly if you have any error in JavaScript code? If all your JavaScript code stops working, you probably have exception, and it should show up in console

Comment: i just relasied it was the 2nd function, just as a quick follow up question. Does the $this selector work in this instance? because it doesn't seem to be doing what im after :/

Comment: Why do you mix `jQuery` and `$`? You shouldn't use `jQuery` at all except when you used `$.noConflict()` - and in this case you should use it only once to make `$` available: `(function($) { your code })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I probably see what's problem here. It should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#mycarousel').each(function(){
    $(this).jcarousel({
      easing: 'backout',
      animation: 1000,
      vertical: true,
      scroll: 1,
      itemVisibleInCallback: {
        // this line binds actual element ("this" from actual function)
        // as "this" for callback function
        onBeforeAnimation: function(){ itemVisibleIn.apply(this,arguments); }
      }
    });
  });
});
```